# Determine if website developed with Django

Tags: python, django

I actually have some questions (real childish).

1) If I know that a website has been developed using django , can we determine from the html source code (by right clicking and choosing "view page source ") , if that website has been developed using django?

2) If I have an HTML code for website written in HTML , and I just want to present it like that using django , how can present this HTML code using django?

3) For what kind of websites , should django be used or are used for ? I mean pure static page , blogs , or a simple google like .

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) No, HTML output can be completely customized with templates. I still think it is detectable with smart analysis of request-response delays; 2) put a badge from http://djangopony.com/ somewhere, it will make it look like 100% django; 3) mostly bigger sites with dynamic contents (such that can change after user interaction).

Comment: If you want to know if the site was written using Django, email the webmaster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, the source depends completely on the person who developed it, and there are no necessary "hints" that it was written in Django.
2. You should at least try the Django tutorial at https://www.djangoproject.com/, you'll learn the basics of setting up a Django application, and you'll answer your own question.
3. Django is pretty general purpose, a bit overkill for static pages. Anything else can be done in Django, the same way it can be done in Ruby on Rails or other Web frameworks.

Answer (score 14):

Here are a few things you could use to determine if a web app was written in Django. None of these are foolproof by any means, but they could be indicators.

- Try http://site.com/admin/ and see if it says "Django site admin" at the top.
- Inspect all of the HTML source code of every form you can find on the site, and see if any contain an input tag with `name='csrfmiddlewaretoken'`. `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is Django's CSRF token identifier. Other web frameworks may use this same name, but Django is the predominant user of it.
- Find information about the site owner and/or developer from a "Contact" page, Google their usernames/emails as well as the word "Django," such as "emailname@gmail.com django". If you see posts or questions about Django, this could possibly mean they use it often.
- If all else fails, simply contact the site owner and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you should do is to test the website behaviour in an unusal stiatuation, for example forcing it to return 404 or 500 error message, which developers often forget to customize.

If you for example go to http://www.galaxyzoo.org/ and then try to determine backend just by looking at HTML, you'll fail.

If, however, you try to access a page 'blablablabla' i.e. http://www.galaxyzoo.org/blablablabla then you'll see 404 message. If you paste the entrie text into google, you'll most likely get hits to Ruby On Rails... :)

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly try www.domainname.com/admin. Some people leave their admin at that url and you can see the login page.

If they left the login page as default, the title tag will say Login | Django site admin or something like that.

For example: http://www.snowbird.com/admin/ (no affiliation)

Answer (score 1):

Django leaves no trace on the html source unless you specifically do. If you only want a static site, django is overkill. Though if you really want to, have a look at django [flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/flatpages/).

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. Yes. See [direct_to_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template)
3. See [djangosites.org](http://djangosites.org)